# How can I find out why AWS ELB believes my service is failing?

Tags: amazon-elb

I have a service which is registered with two target groups : `alb` and `wwwalb`.

The `alb` target group is for internal requests, and the `wwwalb` target group is for external requests.

When I deploy my service, it starts up as it should and starts accepting requests. Looking at the access log, I can see that both the `alb` and `wwwalb` probes the service. Since the service runs in 3 zones, I see 3 requests for each zone, 6 in total.

```
 - - - [19/Jun/2022:20:45:28 +0200] "GET /api/system/status HTTP/1.1" 204 -
 - - - [19/Jun/2022:20:45:28 +0200] "GET /api/system/status HTTP/1.1" 204 -
 - - - [19/Jun/2022:20:45:28 +0200] "GET /api/system/status HTTP/1.1" 204 -
 - - - [19/Jun/2022:20:45:30 +0200] "GET /api/system/status HTTP/1.1" 204 -
 - - - [19/Jun/2022:20:45:30 +0200] "GET /api/system/status HTTP/1.1" 204 -
 - - - [19/Jun/2022:20:45:30 +0200] "GET /api/system/status HTTP/1.1" 204 -
```

Despite this, the service is eventually taken down because the target groups believes the service is unhealthy. In fact, it never seems to think the service is healthy.

[image]

An API call to check on the target group tells me the following :

```
{
    "TargetHealthDescriptions": [
        {
            "Target": {
                "Id": "10.1.143.94",
                "Port": 8182,
                "AvailabilityZone": "eu-north-1b"
            },
            "HealthCheckPort": "8182",
            "TargetHealth": {
                "State": "unhealthy",
                "Reason": "Target.FailedHealthChecks",
                "Description": "Health checks failed"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've been looking at target group metrics, load balancer configurations for a while now - but I simply cannot find anything about the setup which could explain this behaviour. The health check settings seems fine to me as well :

[image]

I just recently added the `wwwalb`, so I'm thinking that somehow having this service in two target groups causes this. Then again, having a service in two target groups is supported and explained by AWS.

Is there a way to get more details from AWS about what's really causing this issue? Any way of looking into why AWS believes the service is failing?

Comment: Do you have any security groups associated with your ALB, and/or your target instances, which might be blocking egress (from the ALB) and/or ingress (to your instances) on that health check port?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how the unhealthy threshold count works when an application is just deployed, but it seems that the unhealthy threshold count of 2 triggered the load balancer to take the application down. The application takes more than a minute to start, and during startup the application will be unresponsive, and will not return a "whitelisted" response code.

Answer (score 0):

I typically set my unhealthy threshold to something higher than my healthy threshold.  Like 2 successful calls with a 10 second interval is healthy, 6 unsuccessful calls with a 10 second interval is unhealthy.

That said, it shouldn't matter and your settings should work. When a target is registering, there is an "initial" state that occurs.  During that time, AWS is trying to validate healthchecks and should only switch to a healthy state if the healthchecks are successful.

[It can take a few minutes for the registration process to complete and health checks to start.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-health-checks.html#:%7E:text=it%20can%20take%20a%20few%20minutes%20for%20the%20registration%20process%20to%20complete%20and%20health%20checks%20to%20start.)

Are you sure your application isn't replying successfully and then failing for a long enough time that it goes unhealthy again? Or is it really that it takes too long to start up and never gets out of the "initial" state?

Comment: the application health check endpoint is a static endpoint which returns a 204 OK. No moving parts involved. But the application takes about 70 seconds to start up, and it seems that AWS failed the application during that time. I have increased the thresholds, and it's running fine now...